# Multiple Divs horizontally - Slide Open / Close Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to have a functionality that when a user clicks on "Label - Filter 1" then the content within div - "Filter_1_Content" appears and the other two divs slide down simultanously. However, when a user clicks on "Label - Filter 2", the content of "Filter 1" should disappear and "Filter 2" should appear while "Filter 3" slides down simoultanously. The same applys to Filter 3 and so on. Please note that at the first load of the page, only the labels should appear.

[image]

This is the jQuery code I currently have and it works for Filter 1. However, the Filter 2 and Filter 3 do not move. Any ideas?

```
<div id="Filter_1">
 <label id="Filter1_Label">Filter 1</label>
  <div id="Filter_1_Content" class"Filters">
   ...content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Filter_2">
 <label id="Filter2_Label">Filter 2</label>
  <div id="Filter_2_Content" class"Filters">
   ...content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Filter_3">
 <label id="Filter2_Label">Filter 3</label>
  <div id="Filter_3_Content" class"Filters">
   ...content
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function SlideDiv() {
 var scopeFilters = $("#Filter1_Label").next(".Filters");
 if (scopeFilters.is(":hidden")) {
     scopeFilters.slideDown('fast');
 } else {
     scopeFilters.slideUp('fast');
 }
};
```

Comment: Where is `#ScopeFilter1_Label` element? Note: `.next()` targets immediately following sibling

Comment: My mistake: Posted the wrong code. Now it should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you need most effectively, you can use common classes and DOM traversal to apply the common logic to a repeated HTML structure. Try this:

```js
var $content = $('.filter-container > div');

$('.filter-container label').click(function() {
  var $target = $(this).next('div');
  $content.not($target).slideUp('fast');
  $target.slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.filter-container > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-container">
  <label>Filter 1</label>
  <div class="filters">
    Content...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter-container">
  <label>Filter 2</label>
  <div class="filters">
    Content...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter-container">
  <label>Filter 3</label>
  <div class="filters">
    Content...
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the above, using incremental `id` attributes is making much more (unnecessary) work for yourself, and would result in much more complex JS code for absolutely no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below logic where you can find parent div and then it's siblings to find other filter divs.
Slide up other filter divs and slideup clicked filter div.

```js
$(function(){
  $("div[id^='Filter_'] label").on("click", function(){
      var $parent = $(this).closest("div");
     $parent.siblings().find("div.Filters").slideUp("fast");
     $(this).next("div.Filters").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Filter_1">
 <label>Filter 1</label>
  <div id="Filter_1_Content" class="Filters">
   ...content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Filter_2">
 <label>Filter 2</label>
  <div id="Filter_2_Content" class="Filters">
   ...content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Filter_3">
 <label>Filter 3</label>
  <div id="Filter_3_Content" class="Filters">
   ...content
  </div>
</div>
```